# How do create multiple processes that will pull messages from rabbitmq?

Tags: python, rabbitmq

Say I have a python script that pulls messages of a queue and process it

```
process_queue_emails.py
```

Now I want to somehow run multiple processes of this file at once, how would I do that?  I need it to run in the background, and I'm guessing on a seperate port? (this is on ubuntu)

So I want to write messages to the queue in my web application, and then I want these worker processes (the .py file above) to recieve and respond to the messages in parallel i.e. I need to run them in their own process.

Comment: Do you want a solution in python, or using a bash-script?

Answer (score 1):

The [zdaemon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zdaemon/2.0.4) module can be used to write demonized processes. Or you can look into the multiprocessing module of Python.  And alternative is using [supervisord](http://www.supervisord.org) for starting arbitrary scripts or programs as daemon.

Comment: +1 for supervisord. Trivially easy to run a script in multiple processes.